# EF Core projection, empty sublist when foreign key is null

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core, projection

I have following query:

```cs
Context.Users.Select(user => new 
{
     Id = user.Id,
     Name = user.Name,
     BankAccounts = user.BankAccounts
          .Select(bankAccount => new  
          {
              Id = bankAccount.Id,
              Name = bankAccount.Name,
              CountryName = bankAccount.Country.Name
          })
})
```

The problem is that bank accounts will result in an empty list only if CountryId ( relational property) is null. If CountryId is not null, I will have one value in List.

Comment: if I understand your question truly you need somthing like CountryName = bankAccount.Country==null? null : bankAccount.Country

Comment: Probably because Country is required relation in Model, but in database is not.